# ParseException - Unparseable date exception in Java

Tags: java, date, date-format

I have oracle database with columns data type   "`TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIME ZONE`" . Which produces
like 14/11/2019 06:30:00, +03:00 in database .

When I am trying to get this timestamp from java
I got `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "28-MAY-12 07.40.03 PM +03:00"` . Our project java version is 6 . I tried with

```
      new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy hh.mm.ss") ,
      new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy hh.mm.ss, Z"),
      new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy hh.mm.ss, z")  ,
      new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy hh.mm.ss, z") ,
      new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy hh.mm.ss, Z") ,
      new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy hh.mm.ss")
```

But none of them worked for me all of throwing `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date error.`

In my java side i have date datatype property in my class and i want to retrieve data from oracle database then parse then set to date data type property like below.

```
serDto.setTarih(new Timestamp(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy hh.mm.ss").parse(str).getTime()));
```

For ex in db timestamp data looks like : 14/11/2019 06:30:00, +03:00 and i want to retrieve as date like above.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where does the string you are trying to parse come from? Is there maybe a way to change its format to something that's easier to parse?

Comment: I am reading xml document element like element.getElementsByTagName("PLZ_ID").item(0).getTextContent() to str then trying to parse.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Timestamp`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead fetch an `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) from your database. Then you may need no parsing.

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution is changing the pattern so that it parses the name of the month and the am/pm marker. Change `MM` to `MMM` and add `a`:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss a").parse(str)
```

However this will ignore the time zone information. It will return a date with the expected time (i.e. 07:40:03 PM) in the default local time zone where this code is running, which might be different from the time zone in the input GMT+0300.

There doesn't seem to be a way to parse `+03:00` into a time zone with `SimpleDateFormat` in Java 6, so if you need to parse the time zone this will require more custom code.